# How to use getpixel() in with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Hello I am testing the getpixel() function in PIL but i keep getting "IndexError: image index out of range."

It works when i do this:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image

image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 1920, 1080))
print(image.getpixel((10,10)))
```

But not when I do this:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image

image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1207, 301, 272, 537))
print(image.getpixel((10,10)))
```

Comment: 272 is less than 1207. `bbox` order is left, upper, right, lower.

Comment: I think the issue is that the bounding box values are all coordinates: `left, top, right, bottom`, not `left, top, width, height`.

Comment: Please share the entire error message,